# Why isn't method defined in application_helper available to use in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

When I put this in the `application_helper.rb`, it is available to use in the view

```rb
def foo
  "bar"
end
```

But when I put this in `application_helper.rb` it is **not** available to use in the view (instead: `NoMethodError  undefined method`)

```rb
def nice_datetime 
  self.strftime('%d %b %-I:%M%p %Z')
end
```

Why is the first method available in the view and the second method not available in the view?

Answer (score 2):

The `self` part is the problem, it is referencing the view itself* and that doesn't have a method called `strftime`. You can fix it somewhat by doing

```rb
def nice_datetime(date)
  date.strftime('...')
end
```

I would however urge you to look into [localization](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).
Which would work something like this, just a very basic setup.

```yaml
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      short: "%H:%M"
```

```
<p><%= l Time.now, format: :short %></p>
```

---

* *That might not be strictly true, I can't remember exactly how helpers are included in the view files, but for sake of this argument is close enough.*